# Limit ponters to 32 bit on 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I have a library which runs fine in 32 bit; however a client needs to link it from a 64 bit application. However, changing the size of pointers is a problem, as we have to store them in 32 bit values.

Is it possible to tell the compiler (both Visual Studio and GCC) to create a 64 bit library, but internally only use a 32 bit address space?

Comment: Explain the magic you used to have a 64-bit application use a 32-bit module in Windows.  Either the app and any external modules it loads is all 64-bit or all 32-bit.

Comment: What do you mean "have to store them in 32bit values". Unless you use a uint32 or datatype as such to store pointers instead of a pointer type, it should be an issue to compile the library for an x64 architecture.

Comment: Also, you could have prevented this (in Windows) if you used [`ULONG_PTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of a known `int` type to store pointers.  Then this all would have been transparent.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no magic, he wants to have a 64bit module that uses a 32bit address space. Of course it won't work, but not for that reason.

Comment: No, this can't be done. When you compile your program in 64bit mode, all pointers use much more than 32 bits (still less than 64 on many platforms, though).

Comment: @SergeyA actually there's the x32 ABI, on linux anyway. Probably won't help either, but it's not like running in 64bit mode necessarily means your pointers have to be 64bit.

Comment: My advice is to change your data type that fits the pointer size type, recompile your code for 64 bits, fix any bugs you find.  Better than trying to finagle around using only 32-bits for a 64-bit type.

Comment: Or the other way around, if your client can compile his application on an x86 architecture, then tell him to use an x86 OS -on a physical machine or a VM. :)

Comment: Because of Address Space Randomisation 64-bit applications will use all 64 bits of the address space so trying to save pointers into 32 bits will truncate the addresses.

Comment: Thanks @harold, that might be what my colleague suggested :) However, it seems it has quite a lot of requirements -it requires the kernel to be recompiled, it seems?

Comment: I cannot use ULONG_PTR because the struct is mapped to the hardware, so I can't change that.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi: Note that X32 is a unique mode that's neither x86 nor x64. The chief problem is that your 64 bit application will be x64, not x32, so having an x32 library is rather pointless. (The idea behind x32 is that you use 32 bits pointers like x86 and all the extra registers that x64 offers you)

Comment: Depending on your exact requirements, perhaps you can change the part of your code that _must store [pointers] in 32-bits_ to use offsets instead. It all depends on why you "must" store pointers in 32-bits. Can you clarify?

Comment: @BeeOnRope we must send them with a fixed protocol which only has a limited number of bits available, simply. Yes using offsets is a solution, but requires significant refactoring of the code. We'll do it if necessary.

Comment: @MSalters so apparently x32 is not a solution. The whole point is linking from x64.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi: That's yet another big sign of problems: you're sending a pointer value to somewhere else? What's the other side going to be doing with the value? Pointers only have local meaning.

Comment: @MSalters I didn't write it... it's just stored for a while and then sent back to a different function running on the same process which sent it, so that it ends up making sense again.  It would be non trivial to know where to send it without making this trip.

Comment: Your best bet then is to convert only the pointers into offsets, or simply 32-bit indexes into a pointer table that holds 64-bit pointers. Presumably the amount of code that needs to deal with these "portable" pointers is much smaller than the total pointer use in the program.

Comment: The "pointer to pointer" technique is sometimes called a _handle_.

Answer (score 0):

No. `sizeof(void*)` is very much a constant. It can be 4 or 8, but not 4 **and** 8.